# Redux async function structure?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to find out why I am failing to recieve the dispatch() function from redux-thunk that is suppose to be passed. I have tried several different  coding tutorials but none seems to work for me, but what I did notice is that there were several different types of implementations.

So my question is simple, what is the overall correct way of writing an async function for redux-thunk to ensure dispatch is called?

Note I am able to call the action creator, but errors:
1) dispatch is not an action
2) action needs to be a plain object

my understanding of what I am asking for is  redux async action.

```js
const getAttributes= () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return (/* Some async stuff */);
  }
}
```

Am I wrong?

My store configurations are:

```js
import { createStore,applyMiddleware,combineReducers,compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {logger} from 'redux-logger';
import {inventoryFilter,availableAttributes} from '../reducers/reducer';


const Store = createStore(

///combine imported reducers
combineReducers({
    activeFilter:inventoryFilter,
    availableAttributes:availableAttributes

},applyMiddleware(thunk,logger)

));



export default Store;
```

index.js

Then I connect it to the provider in React as such, but since Redux is actually independent of, I make the Store.Disptach() call before and React Component just to test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import FilterBar from './SideBar/FilterBar';
import Store from '../redux/store/mainStore';
import { REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE_FILTER,ADD_ATTRIBUTE_TO_FILTER, removeAttribute, addAttribute,getAttributes } from '../redux/actions/actions';

Store.subscribe(()=>{
    console.log("store changes", Store.getState())
})

Store.dispatch(getAttributes())


if (document.getElementById('InventoryDisplay')) {
  
        
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={Store}>
        <FilterBar/>
        </Provider>
        ,document.getElementById('FilterBar'));

   
}
```

Errors are:
1) Dispatch is not a function.
2) Action needs to be a plain object

Comment: Did you wireup middle ware?

Comment: I can not understand the cause of this error with this much of information, you might be missing proper configuration of thunk or binding the actions to component. You can check my basic repository for react redux and let me know if you have any questions.
https://github.com/brijeshbhakta30/create-react-redux-app

Comment: Yeah i agree with comment above, at a glance your code looks ok so it may be something wrong outside the block you posted

Comment: @BrijeshBhakta, I have updated my post with additional code. I literally implemented redux-thunk on another app without error, I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: @Femi oni, I would love your input on the updated post

Comment: One common mistake is not wrapping your action in your controller with connect. in that case dispatch will be undefined. That is the absence of mapdispatchToProps

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your redux/thunk config. Slightly different from how i do it but looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the async stuff **and** dispatch an action in there (plain object with type property.

Comment: @timotgl, I was asking because, I thought the structure of the function was the problem it seems that it is not, the issue still remains, I updated the post with additional supporting code. Maybe I am calling dispatch incorrectly. No clue

Answer (score 0):

It might happen in the component page when binding the actions. something like,

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(
      {
        action1,
        action2,
        ...
      },
      dispatch
    )
  };
}
```

More code is needed.